How to turn off banding effect in unity URP?
I am currently writnig a voxel terrain rendering system in unity.
But, I keep getting this weird banding effect in unity while using URP. What is causing this? Is there any way to get rid of it?
The entire terrain should just be green, the brown and white are extra additions that I don't understand where they appear from.

I have tried disabling the fog option in lightning tab under rendering settings in the window menu, but that seems to have done nothing.
I have also tried using a custom unlit shader with nothing but texture mapping on the output (not even lightning) but I still can't see a difference. This is what my fragment function looks like.
fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
{
    fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
    return col;
}


mipmap? LOD? point filter?

The texture atlas I'm using to render the blocks is imported with Point filtering option. I haven't messed about with the other settings though.

That could be a problem with mipmap, try to disable it.

Disabling mipmap only makes the issue worse. Removing point filtering fixes the issue but that only serves to make the texture blurry. Is there anything else I can do to fix this issue?
